# How to persuade one that cloud platform is safe enough?

Tags: security, google-hangouts, slack, facebook-messenger

I am a co-founder of a startup company. We are not doing things of computer science or programming. We're making our own product. As a result, My partner and I use some cloud platform service, for instance, Google Drive, Slack, Facebook Messenger, and Google Hangout, to support us. We use them to share files of our development. The problem is that my partner is not a person who studies computer science or has enough background of information security. So he always hesitating to use those services to share important files. For example, with Slack, we can share code snippet in our team channels, but he think we should **encrypt** our *code file* to avoid any information leakage. I think encryption will lose the convenience feature to use such service. How do I convince my partner that he doesn't need to worry about the safety issue to share code or file on cloud platform services?

Comment: You should aim to make your business operate within a security framework such as [cyber essentials](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/cyber-essentials-scheme-overview) or ISO27001. This way you can evaluate the operational risks of your business in a standard manner.  Your partner may be focussing too much on a single aspect of security, while ignoring other, potentially gaping holes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very open-ended question, primarily because we don't know your partner.

Essentially, irrespective of how safe your platform is, it's only as safe as the hosts machine is—gain access to that and all the files are still compromised anyway.

Most of the day-to-day work can be done through the platforms mentioned however extremely sensitive files (e.g. server keys) should be passed physically through a data storage device (e.g. pendrive).

If you are geographical apart, you can transfer sensitive documents using [PGP](https://www.symantec.com/encryption/) instead. For messenging you could use something such as [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) or [Signal](https://www.symantec.com/encryption/).